# Group by Map in Groovy

Tags: groovy, collections, grouping

```
[
  programs:  [
    trip: [
      [
        description: "",
        tripName: "Niagra",
        scheduleProgramTime: "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
        country: "USA"
      ],
      [
        description: "",
        tripName: "Chennai",
        scheduleProgramTime : "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
        country: "India"
      ],
      [
        description: "",
        tripName: "Niagra",
        scheduleProgramTime: "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
        country: "USA"
      ]
    ],
    trip: [   // Editor note: this line is in error. a map cannot have two properties named "trip". In practice this compiles, but when run the SECOND "trip" wipes out the FIRST. -- @BalRog
      [
        description: "",
        tripName: "South Africa",
        scheduleProgramTime: "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
        country: "Africa"
      ],
      [
        description: "",
        tripName: "Chennai",
        scheduleProgramTime: "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
        country: "India"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

This is my Map and I am trying to groupBy based on the tripName(Niagra/Chennai/South Africa). Output I need is like

```
[
  "Niagra": [
    [
      description: "",
      tripName: "Niagra",
      scheduleProgramTime: "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00"
      country: "USA"
    ],
    [
      description: "",
      tripName: "Niagra",
      scheduleProgramTime: "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00"
      country: "USA"
    ]
  ],
  "Chennai": [
    [
      description: "",
      tripName: "Chennai",
      scheduleProgramTime: "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00"
      country: "India"
    ]
  ],
  "South Africa": [
    [
      description: "",
      tripName: "South Africa",
      scheduleProgramTime: "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00"
      country: "Africa"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I tried using this `cityMap.trip.groupBy({it.tripName})` but not getting the proper output.
Thanks in advance.

I have changed it to Map. Now previously I have given curly braces instead of "[]" braces.Now based on the Map can you please provide me the details.

Comment: The input and desired output here both look a little like JSON and a little like groovy Map/List literals, but in fact are not correct syntax for either. Which were you going for, JSON, or Groovy Map/List literals?

In particular, in neither JSON nor Groovy can you have two object properties with the same name. You apparently have two properties named "trip" inside the same Map/Object.

Comment: I m going with groovy map/list combination

Comment: Let me fix the syntax for you then; edit forthcoming. The symantic error (two "trip" keys in the same Map) will remain. You will have to resolve that one.

Comment: I fixed the Groovy Map/List literal syntax, but annotated the logic error in your input Map/List literal.

Comment: Now, assuming your given input is assigned to a variable called ```cityMap```, and that you fix the noted logic error, the following should give you the desired results: ```cityMap.programs.trip.groupBy{it.tripName}```

Answer (score 3):

First, start with a proper Groovy `Map`. Your example is not a Groovy `Map`, however it does look like JSON. If so, you can parse it with [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) to get something `Map`-like. **Then** you can use `groupBy()` on the *trip* object:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText("""{
  "trip": [
    {
      "description": "",
      "tripName": "Niagra",
      "scheduleProgramTime": "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
      "country" : "USA"
    },
    {
      "description": "",
      "tripName": "Chennai",
      "scheduleProgramTime": "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
      "country" : "India"
    },
    {
      "description": "",
      "tripName": "Niagra",
      "scheduleProgramTime": "2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
      "country" : "USA"
    }
    ]
}
""")

json.trip.groupBy { it.tripName }
```

The output looks like this:

```
[
    'Niagra': [
        ['country':'USA', 'description':'', 'scheduleProgramTime':'2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00', 'tripName':'Niagra'], 
        ['country':'USA', 'description':'', 'scheduleProgramTime':'2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00', 'tripName':'Niagra']
     ], 


    'Chennai':[
        ['country':'India', 'description':'', 'scheduleProgramTime':'2000-01-01T00:00:00-05:00', 'tripName':'Chennai']
    ],
]
```

Comment: I have changed the braces in my question.I need it for map.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you can just skip the JSON parsing part.

Comment: Thanks Rosa. I have one additional question.I am updating my question once

Comment: If you have an additional question, please leave this one as-is and post a new question.

Comment: Sorry Rosa,By mistake I have changed my question here. I will be more than grateful if you can provide a solution for it.